# I can't make ImageMagick work from a browser

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert a PDF file to JPG files.
The PDF is created using Prince, and immediately after, I call the function that calls ImageMagick. Here's the content of the said function:

```
if (!file_exists(Settings::getPDFFilePath())) {
    Log::l(true, "ERROR: File \"" . Settings::getPDFFilePath() . "\" doesn't exist.");
    throw new SeverityException(SeverityException::MISSINGPDFFILE);
}

if ((!file_exists(Settings::getPreviewJPGDirectory())) && (!mkdir(Settings::getPreviewJPGDirectory()))){
    Log::l(true, "ERROR: Preview JPG directory couldn't be created.");
    throw new SeverityException(SeverityException::UNWRITABLE_BOOK_DIRECTORY);
} elseif (!chmod(Settings::getPreviewJPGDirectory(), 0777)) {
    /** Files might be modified by other script/user. */
    Log::l(true, "WARNING: Access rights could not be modified for Preview JPG directory. Any further modification might become impossible.");
    Settings::submitException(new SeverityException(SeverityException::JPG_DIR_RIGHTS_UNMODIFIABLE));
}
$convert = "/usr/local/bin/convert -quality 100 -density 100x100 /path/to/pdf/file.pdf /path/to/jpg/file.jpg 2>&1";
exec($convert, $output, $res);
```

Here's the thing:
When I call ImageMagick from a command-line with my user or the user _www, it works.
When I call the php script from a command-line, using my user or the user _www, it works.
But when I call the php script from a browser (ImageMagick is then called by the user _www, I've checked) I get this error:

> convert: no images defined `/path/to/jpg/file.jpg\' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.'

The pdf file permissions are 666 and the jpg's destination folder's permissions are 777.

I doubt that the problem comes from Prince, and it seems obvious to me that it's not access-rights related either.
Both command-line mode and Apache use the same php.ini file (/etc/php.ini).

I may have missed something, but I really don't know what...

Edit: Oh, and I'm using MacOS Maverick, but I don't think that's relevant.
Edit2: I just tried with pdftopng (look XPDF up for more info) and it works fine. So the problem definitely comes from ImageMagick.

Comment: Do you have spaces in your filenames maybe? You really should quote them in your `convert` command.

Comment: Nope, no space in directory or file names. Never ever! :-)
I'll add the quotes, though - better safe...

Comment: Have you got any environment variables set differently between your user and the www user? Can you test with real, absolute paths to input and output image, i.e. path starting with `/`

Comment: I don't think so, and anyway I only use absolute paths both for ImageMagick and the source/destination files.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll go with XPDF...
It works fine and has no dependencies (ImageMagick => GhostScript).
Thanks anyway @MarkSetchell !